# Return type is incorrect, but I don't understand what it should be

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to redo this method to only return the appropriate records.  The original GetAll() below returns a lot of unnecessary columns and data because EF proxies are being used.  Turning the EF proxies off breaks stuff in the app, so I'm trying to selectively reduce data returned to improve performance.

Original GetAll()

```
    public IEnumerable<OWF_ManagerRelationship> GetAll()
    {
    return context.OWF_ManagerRelationship.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
    }
```

The new GetAll() I'm trying to create is below.  This one will have some fields from the OWF_Onsites table in the commented out Include() statement.  These will be a couple date fields and one integer field.  This is where I'm attempting to reduce the amount of data returned from this method to the calling one.  I want to return the one DisplayName field from the Owf_ManagerRelationship context and the other 3 (OnsiteDate, TargetDate, TargetMonth) from the OWF_Onsites table.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        var managers = context.OWF_ManagerRelationship
            .Where(m => m.IsActive.Value == true)
            //.Include(o => o.OWF_Onsites).Where()
            .Select(x => new {x.DisplayName})
            .ToList();

        return managers;         
    }
```

The `return managers` above has red squiggles.  It says "Cannot convert expression type `System.Collections.Generic.List<DisplayName:string>` to return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`".

I understand that it can't convert the anonymous type string DisplayName to return type string, but I don't really understand why.  I thought it would work because the DisplayName is a string.  I also don't understand what the return type should be once I get the code in the Include() statement working.  It should also return the two date fields and the one integer field from OWF_Onsites once this has been done.

Can some one please shine some light on what this should look like?  Including some code and how to use the two date fields(targetDate and OnsiteDate) and integer(TargetMonth) field from the OWF_Onsites table in the Include() would be really helpful.

Hopefully, my intent here is clear in case my attempt to do it is way off base.  Please let me know if I'm doing this all wrong.

Comment: Can simplify `m.IsActive.Value == true` to `m.IsActive.Value`

Comment: Take a look at the ViewModel pattern (or DTOs) and Automapper. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/07/08/entity-framework-extensions-for-automapper/

Comment: Depending on your front end, you could also look at OData to project your data. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to return an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type instead of `IEnumerable<string>`. Remove the `new` in the select and it will work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
{
    var managers = context.OWF_ManagerRelationship
        .Where(m => m.IsActive.Value == true)
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
        .ToList();

    return managers;         
}
```

Some other things of note:
You can also simplify your code by omitting `.ToList()` since `.Select` will already return and `IEnumerable<string>`. Note you will still have to enumerate the query later on (using `ToList` for example) to get the results because of deferred execution.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
{
    var managers = context.OWF_ManagerRelationship
        .Where(m => m.IsActive.Value == true)
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName);

    return managers;         
}
```

Comment: Is there a need to call `ToList()`? Won't `Select()` return an `IEnumerable()`?

Comment: @ryuu9187 Just calling `Select` will return an `IQueryable<string>`. It is necessary to call `ToList` for example (or `ToArray()`, foreach) to materialize the query.

Comment: You can return the results without `ToList()`, the return type of the method will automatically cast it to `IEnumerable`. Whether you *want* to return a deferred result that can be executed any number of times inadvertently by the consumer is a different issue.

Comment: @GertArnold True but I don't think he wants deferred execution (especially since it's just a collection of strings he needs).

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Thanks that took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at IQueryable projections to do what you are trying to do.  Here are a few great blog posts on getting started:

- [Queryable-Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)
- [stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code)

By using these concepts I am able to write a generic repository method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllProjectTo<T>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] filters)
{
    var query = Table.AsQueryable();
    if (filters != null)
    {
        query = filters.Aggregate(query, (current, where) => current.Where(where));
    }

    return query.Project().To<T>().AsEnumerable();
}
```

What this means is if I have this data definition (EF):

```
public class FullModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And I want only this representation from the data:

```
public class ShortModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
}
```

I can now do this:

```
IEnumerable<ShortModel> results = _repository.GetAllProjectTo<ShortModel>(a => a.Title.Contains("milk"));
```

The secret sauce in the above is the definition of Project() and To().  (Read through the sample in the 2nd blog I posted.)  What these two methods do, in tandem, is affect the SQL being sent to SQL Server.  In the code sample you have above, even with the Select, it will issue a **SELECT * FROM** command then apply the SELECT during materialization.  This means, all the data in all the affected rows is being brought back to you first!

---

In your case, it might look like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // Name of field MUST match name of field in EF/ORM...
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllManagers()
{
    var displayList = context.OWF_ManagerRelationship
        .Where(m => m.IsActive.Value == true)
        .Project()
        .To<MyViewModel>()
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<string> managers = displayList.Select(a => a.DisplayName).ToList();

    return managers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It will be useful to reduce the number of records returned.